# Reference request: set theory of sigma algebras

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, set-theory

I am studying Billingsley's *Probability and Measure*. The section on sigma-fields (Section 2) seems to demand set-theoretic reasoning beyond what I have been exposed to so far in undergraduate algebra and analysis texts.

For example consider the statement:

> If $\Omega$ is uncountable, then it contains a set $A$ such that $A$
>   and $A^c$ are both uncountable.

or the exercise

> Show that, if $B \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$, then there exists a
>   countable subclass $\mathcal{A}_B$ of $\mathcal{A}$ such that 
>   $B \in\sigma(\mathcal{A}_B)$.

I would greatly appreciate set-theory references from which I can learn techniques for addressing questions like the above. I have looked at Devlin's *Joy of Sets* and similar books but I'm not sure if they are what I really need.

To clarify, my request is not for answers to the above questions but for references that will help me with the techniques needed to answer them on my own.

Comment: Look at the book "Probability & Measure Theory" by Robert B Ash, Catherine A Doleans-Dade.

Comment: For the first statement, use the well-ordering theorem to enumerate $\Omega$, and then just divide it into even and odd parts as you would divide a countable set. (Limit ordinals count as even, of course.)

Comment: The first question cannot be solved explicitly because it must use the axiom of choice somehow (it is otherwise consistent that there is an uncountable set which cannot be written as a disjoint union of two uncountable sets); and the second question was recently asked and answered on this very site.

Comment: @AsafKaragila My request was not so much for answers to the questions but for references that will help me tackle such questions on my own.

Comment: I was just pointing those things out. Had I thought you were looking for particular answers I would have suggested these questions are duplicates (and they would have been).

Comment: @AsafKaragila. Thanks.

Comment: The key tool you need to familiarize yourself with is Zorn's lemma. If you are not familiar with well-orderings, Zorn's lemma will probably feel more intuitive, and there are many examples of its applications in algebra and analysis.